# Right Click SaveAs and Open C# Application

Tags: c#, architecture, file-handling

I am wanting to develop a C# application that would allow me to right click on a file and choose an option within the context menu to perform a save as with a date time stamp and then open the newly created file.

The process flow would look something like this:

- User right clicks on a file opening the context menu
- User selects "Save As and Open"
- The original file (filename.txt) is saved as (filename_08292017_093705.txt)
- The new file is then opened

The application would handle the following:

- Collect the file path and filename
- Poll the date time info from the PC
- Save a copy of the file with the date time info
- Open the new file

In summery what I am ultimately after is a high level overview of the steps I would need to take to make this work, such as what libraries to use, tips on how to structure the code, or even a code example.

I'll do my best to answer any questions or provide more details if needed. I am a controls engineer with structured text programming experience within the industrial automation realm, but have next to no Windows programming experience and am looking to learn.

Thanks

Comment: Are you talking about Windows Explorer integration? There are a lot of "Too Broad" close votes, but I think a little more information might turn this around.

Answer (score 1):

Each step in your second list of bullet points is really simple to do, literally a couple of lines of code for each, so discussing structure is a bit moot.  You also don't *need* any frameworks or libraries here, everything you need can be done with .Net easily.

The windows explorer integration is easily done by adding a key to the registry.  If you don't want to put that in by-hand and want some sort of installer then that's another kettle of fish, but if I were you i'd approach that separately after you have the integration working to begin with.

I'd suggest getting stuck in, and then asking finer grained questions as/when you come up against issues.